# Why is my Cloth floating above the Collision Object?

Tags: cloth-simulation

Haven't spent much time with cloth sims but I need one now and I'm having a hard time understanding why it won't rest on the surface of my object.

(NOTE: I've created a cross section of the objects in question for illustrative purposes.)

Would love some suggestions/guidance.

[PROJECT FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/2c7us9djhjde83inl56yn/Cloth-Floating-Why.blend?rlkey=wzlogvoryvz1fskofvpvfv69w&dl=0)

[image]

Comment: Check the collision distance on the ***collider*** object, from memory I think it's like 15mm/the better part of an inch or so - total gap is cloth collision distance ***plus*** collider object distance

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the collision object and under *Softbody & Cloth > Thickness Outer*, lower the value down to the minimum:

[image]

Comment: That was it, thank you. I knew I was missing a detail but I lost patience trying to diagnose it ;)